# Clashing global and local variable name

Tags: go, scope, shadowing

Here is the code snippet in question:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var a string = "hello"

func main() {
    b := "world"

    fmt.Println(a, b)

    a := "bye"

    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
bye world
```

My question is, how do I resolve name clash between the "global" and "local" variables `a`?

More specifically, how do I tell Go which `a` to use?

Comment: Wait, it's not a "clash" but rather what is called "shadowing." Are you asking whether there is a way for code inside `main` to refer to the global `a` even though the inner `a` is shadowing (hiding) it?

Comment: BTW this might help: https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/go-gotcha-1-variable-shadowing-within-inner-scope-due-to-use-of-operator/ (found it by Googling "golang shadow")

Comment: If you want to change the value of the global variable just do `a = "bye"` instead of `a := "bye"`

Comment: @RayToal yes, that's what I am asking for, but as it seems from the answers below that might not be possible.

Comment: It is possible in many other programming languages (e.g., C++ has `::`, Ada has `subprogram.name`), but Go doesn't seem to have a way to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your original example illustrates the situation well. Just like most in programming languages the scope matters.

The scoping closest to the use is what decides the value of `a`. So if you redeclare (`:=`) the variable inside your function, then for the duration of that function you will have the value `"bye"`.

If you chose to use the same name for two things, the consequence is that the inner name will always dominate. If you need both values then name the variables differently.

Comment: Is there a way to use both variables with same name and different scopes?

Comment: No. Variables are referenced by name. If two have the same name, you'll only be able to refer to one of them in any given scope.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is not really a solution but a workaround. Before creating a shadowning variable, you can make a pointer to an outside variable.

```
var a string = "hello"

func main() {
    b := "world"

    fmt.Println(a, b)

    pa := &a
    a := "bye"

    fmt.Println(*pa, b, a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called variable shadowing.
You just name them differently.

You can't just ask go to behave differently.