# the Insert operation must have a Deployment set before Execute can be called

Tags: mongodb, go, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS instance with MongoDB running. I am trying to do a small db operation which seems to work when the files included below was written inside a single go file. When I try to split it I get the following error

> the Insert operation must have a Deployment set before Execute can be called

The split files are given below

connect.go

```html
package db

import (
 "context"
 "fmt"
 "log"

 "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
 "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var Client1 mongo.Client

func Connect() {
 // Set client options
 clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("remote_url")

 // Connect to MongoDB
 Client1, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 // Check the connection
 err = Client1.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
}

func main() {
 fmt.Println("Connection to MongoDB done.")
}
```

main.go

```html
package main

import (
 "context"
 "fmt"
 "log"

 "db"

 "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

// You will be using this Trainer type later in the program
type Trainer struct {
 Name string
 Age  int
 City string
}

func main() {

 db.Connect()
 collection := db.Client1.Database("test2").Collection("trainers")
 _ = collection

 fmt.Println("Created collection", _)

 ash := Trainer{"Ash", 10, "Pallet Town"}
 // misty := Trainer{"Misty", 10, "Cerulean City"}
 // brock := Trainer{"Brock", 15, "Pewter City"}

 insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), ash)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 fmt.Println("Inserted a single document: ", insertResult)

 err = db.Client1.Disconnect(context.TODO())

 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
 fmt.Println("Connection to MongoDB closed.")
}
```

They are placed in the following structure

/src -> main.go
/src -> /db/connect.go

Comment: Are you using go modules? How are you compiling / running your app?

Comment: No, i am not using go modules.

I compile it using command:

`go run main.go`

Comment: @SidharthV, I hope you solved your issue. If not read [this article](https://codershood.info/2020/02/15/golang-and-mongodb-connection-tutorial) . Still, if you dint understand let me know I will write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your problem is caused by [variable shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624326/clashing-global-and-local-variable-name) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) and you're initializing a local variable and not the global `mongo.Client` object, hence [throwing the error](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/1245030cf0e2dd51a0ffc0cdfe916c0d3654e960/x/mongo/driver/operation/insert.go#L85) that you're getting.

It happens in your `connect.go` file, where you have defined two different `Client1` variables with the same name:

1. One at global scope
2. Another in `Connect()` that gets declared+initialised when calling `mongo.Connect()`

   ```
   var Client1 mongo.Client // Client1 at global scope

   func Connect() {
       // Set client options
       clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("remote_url")

       // Connect to MongoDB
       Client1, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions) // Client1 at local scope within Connect()
   ```

That causes that the one at global scope is never initialised so main.go crashes when trying to use it because it's nil.

There are several ways to solve this, for example by using a different name for the variable at local scope and assign the client to the global one:

```
    var Client1 mongo.Client

    func Connect() {
        // Set client options
        clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("remote_url")

        // Connect to MongoDB
        Client1Local, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
        Client1 = *Client1Local
```

Or avoid declaring the local variable and directly initialise the one at global scope:

```
    var Client1 *mongo.Client // Note that now Client1 is of *mongo.Client type

    func Connect() {
        // Set client options
        clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("remote_url")

        // Connect to MongoDB
        var err error
        Client1, err = mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions) // Now it's an assignment, not a declaration+assignment anymore
```

More about Golang's variable shadowing discussion at [Issue#377 proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/377)

Comment: Wow, thank you for explaining the issue and fixing the problem. Even though I did manage to fix the issue by using another method but I always wondered why this  code didn't work. I with your explanation I understood the issue. I once again thank you for the effort you put in for presenting a great answer.

Comment: You are more than welcome :) And glad to hear that you managed to get it working anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include like, since the you have omitted the db directory , that might have be the issue

```
import "db/db"
```

Also there is main() in connect.go there should be only one main package and main() function for a project.

```
---------------- Try what is discussed below exactly ------------
```

Ok this is my test setup with directory tree of code similar to yours:

```
[user@devsetup src]$ tree test
        test
        ├── dbtest
        │   └── db
        │       └── connect.go
        ├── main // This is executable file
        └── main.go

    2 directories, 3 files
```

In connect.go i havent changed anything but removed the main() as mentioned above.
Make sure you use only exported functions and variables , Exported functions/Variables starts with Capital letter. 
In main.go looks like the code below.
* Go to dbtest/db directory and run `go install` command. then go the project directory , ie `test` here in this case, and run `go build main.go or go build .`

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"

        "test/dbtest/db"

        // "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

// You will be using this Trainer type later in the program
type Trainer struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
        City string
}

func main() {

        db.Connect()
        collection := db.Client1.Database("test2").Collection("trainers")
        _ = collection

        // fmt.Println("Created collection", _)

        ash := Trainer{"Ash", 10, "Pallet Town"}
        // misty := Trainer{"Misty", 10, "Cerulean City"}
        // brock := Trainer{"Brock", 15, "Pewter City"}

        insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), ash)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Inserted a single document: ", insertResult)

        err = db.Client1.Disconnect(context.TODO())

        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Connection to MongoDB closed.")
}
```

This is my binary output since i havent given any input url , it is throwing an error.Seems working. I have commented out a package and a line in main.go

```
[user@devsetup test]$ ./test
20xx/yy/zz aa:bb:cc error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"
```

Comment: explained a bit , try this now

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, I will try that and comment the result here.